# What is the iCAL property for using the user's local time?

Tags: timezone, icalendar, power-automate

I've created a Power Automate flow that generates an ICS file for a meeting invite that will be sent to people across the US in different time zones.

Everything is working as I had hoped, but I can't find the property that needs to be set in order to use the end user's local time. It always shows up in UTC.

Comment: Can you provide some code that reflects what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The way that the event's start/stop time is displayed to the end-user depends on how the end-user's calendar program is designed/configured. It has nothing to do with the data in the ICS file.

Google Calendar, for example, will automatically convert from whatever time zone the ICS file uses to the user's local time zone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if this is the case, if I set DTSART and DTEND and specify a timezone (tzid), then the invitees' Outlook SHOULD convert the meeting to their local timezone?

Comment: @newtothis That's what I observed on Google Calendar and it makes sense for it to be working that way, however it would be nice if someone could confirm that it is indeed how it should be. Essentially whether the timezones on DTSTART/DTEND have an influence at all (apart from computing the absolute timestamp from the given datetime).